# Working jQuery in link to add fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails app I have this code

```
<%= form_for @experience, url: experience_path do |f| %>      
    <div class="experselect end-date">
        <%= f.label :experience_end, class: "profile_label" %><br />
      <%= f.date_select :experience_end, {start_year: 1945, discard_day: true, order: [ :day, :month, :year ]}, :html=> {class: 'date-select'} %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-checkbox current-item">
      <%= f.check_box :experience_current, class: 'is_current', id: "checkbox_id" %>
      I currently work here
    </div>
<%= f.submit "Update experience" %>
```

And I have a link_to_add_fields method that add the same form as this I have also this script that disable the experience_end when the checkbox is checked and it works great.

```
function disableEndDate(thisObj) {
    var targetedSelect = thisObj.closest(".form-checkbox").prev(".experselect").find("select");

    if (thisObj.prop("checked")) {

        targetedSelect.prop(
            'disabled', true);
        targetedSelect.css(
            "background-color", "#D9D8DD");


    } else {
        targetedSelect.prop(
            'disabled', false);
        targetedSelect.css(
            "background-color", "#FFFFFF");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[class='is_current']").click(function () {
      disableEndDate($(this));
  });
});
```

But actually my problem is when checkbox and submit the form and try to edit it again i find that the checkbox is checked and the select is disabled but the background of the select is not #D9D8DD as expected

Answer (score 1):

You have to reach your select starting from your checkbox. For this, you 'll need to pass `$(this)`parameter to your `disableEndDate()` function on click event :

```
$("input[class='is_current']").click(function () {
    disableEndDate($(this));
});
```

---

Now your function is ready to get your clicked checkbox element. And you also know that DIVs containing input and select are nested.

> You get `targetedSelect` starting at your checkbox. You reach the parent div *(.form-checkbox)*, then the previous div containing the select element *(.form-checkbox)*, and finally, find the select.

So :

```
function disableEndDate(thisObj) {
    var targetedSelect = thisObj.closest(".form-checkbox").prev(".experselect").find("select");

    if (thisObj.prop("checked")) {

        targetedSelect.prop(
            'disabled', true);
        targetedSelect.css(
            "background-color", "#D9D8DD");


    } else {
        targetedSelect.prop(
            'disabled', false);
        targetedSelect.css(
            "background-color", "#FFFFFF");
    }
}
```

---

> [Live exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/jrn4er6x/)

Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you very much for your help it is working great there is only one problem that when I submit the form with checkbox checked and try to edit it again the select is disabled but the background is not "#D9D8DD"

Comment: I have edit my question with the code you have suggested to me

Comment: There is not the part of your code concerning the submit

Comment: Unable to reproduce the issue into the fiddle. Adding a class instead of modifying inline css may work : https://jsfiddle.net/jrn4er6x/1/